# Get PartitionedList for partition with more than 2000 documents

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cloudant

I have a partitioned Cloudant database (on the free tier) with a partition that has more than 2000 documents. Unfortunately, running `await db.partitionedList('partitionID')` returns this object:

```
{
  total_rows: 2082,
  offset: 0,
  rows: [...]
}
```

where rows is an array of only 2000 objects. Is there a way for me to get those 82 remaining rows, or get a list of all 2082 rows together. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cloudant limits the `_partition` endpoints to returning a maximum of 2000 rows](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-limits#query-results) so you can't get all 2082 rows at once.

The way to get the remaining rows is by storing the doc ID of the last row and using it to make a `startkey` for a second request, appending `\0` to ask the list to start from the next doc ID in the index e.g.

```js
db.partitionedList('partitionID', {
  startkey: `${firstResponse.rows[1999].id}\0`
})
```

Note that `partitionedList` is the equivalent of `/{db}/_partition/{partitionID}/_all_docs` so `key` and `id` are the same in each row and you can safely assume they are unique (because it is a doc ID) allowing use the [unicode `\0` trick](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-pagination-and-bookmarks#option-2-the-u0000-trick). However, if you wanted to do the same with a `_view` you'd need to store both the `key` and `id` and [fetch the 2000th row twice](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-pagination-and-bookmarks#pagination-of-views).